# Where i can edit this price element woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I want to replace the word "De: " of all products, but I do not know where

[Link to website](https://www.thepanamaexperience.com/categoria-producto/one-day-tours/)

[image: Element to replace]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the "From" text via the [`woocommerce_get_price_html_from_text`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/fadfa4d90379ab577e6908b66715bf93b3038bf4/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2546) filter.

You would do so, like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html_from_text', 'so_43054760_price_html_from_text' );
function so_43054760_price_html_from_text( $text ){
    return __( 'whatever', 'your-plugin-textdomain' );
}
```

Keep in mind this is WooCommerce 3.0-specific code. I'm not sure it is back-compatible with WC 2.6.x.